# join and where clause in hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am using join and where clause in hibernate 3.but i cant reach the solution.I got the error.

```
Query qry= session.createQuery("SELECT addemployee.eid,addemployee.fname,addemployee.location,"
        + "empdet.jtitle,empdet.leadname FROM addemployee LEFT JOIN empdet ON addemployee.eid = empdet.eid WHERE (addemployee.eid ='"+id+"')");

        List l = qry.list();
        Iterator it=l.iterator();

        while(it.hasNext())
        {

            Object rows[] = (Object[])it.next();
            System.out.println(rows[0]+separator+rows[1]+separator+rows[2]+separator+rows[3]+separator+rows[4]);
        }
```

Issue:   org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ON near line 1, column 127 [SELECT addemployee.eid,addemployee.fname,addemployee.location,empdet.jtitle,empdet.leadname FROM addemployee LEFT JOIN empdet ON addemployee.eid = empdet.eid WHERE (addemployee.eid ='206')]

Comment: Which DB is it? What happens when you run this query directly on DB using a tool like DBVis or SQL developer? SyntaxException suggests that it is wrongly formatted

Comment: It looks like you're trying to pass SQL to a method that requires HQL.  Have you tried with `createSQLQuery` instead of `createQuery`?

Comment: is your `addemployee.eid` a String or an Integer?

Comment: I am using Mysql 5.7

Comment: eid-integer and rest of the fields hold varchar.

Comment: Thanks all.I got the output.i used createSQLQuery instead of createQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `session.createSQLQuery()` instead.

and don't put enclosed apostrophe (''), you are inputting `numbers`, not `varchar`.

like this.

```
Query qry= session.createSQLQuery("SELECT addemployee.eid,addemployee.fname,addemployee.location,"
    + "empdet.jtitle,empdet.leadname FROM addemployee LEFT JOIN empdet ON addemployee.eid = empdet.eid WHERE (addemployee.eid ="+id+")");
```

Comment: `charvar` what is that? did you mean `varchar`?

Comment: @Rahul noted. im just shortening the term of Character Varying to charvar. Thanks by the way. I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate Session's `createQuery()` method requires *valid HQL syntax*. You can check how to write joins [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins-forms).
Basically, in HQL you *work with your entities, not SQL tables*. So you don't need to write *ON*, because you already map association between entities.

If you still want to write native SQL query, you need to use
`session.createSQLQuery();` instead